# How to align html textbox to my image?

Tags: html, css, web

HOW TO ALIGN THEM LIKE THIS

[image]

MY CODE IN HTML

```
<div id="headerlogo">
    <a href="http://localhost/absolutevc/index.html">
      <img id="logo" src="images\logo.jpg" height="69" width="250">
    </a>
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Keywords" name="search" size="50px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex`

```
#headerlogo{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is my fiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/nz0exkez/